# Why does accessing an index of 0 length array not throw an out of bounds access violation error?

Tags: arrays, fortran, intel-fortran

Using intel fortran oneapi version 2023.0.0.25839. I've turned on all run-time checks using /check:all.

If the following throws a "forrtl: severe (408): fort: (2): subscript #1 of the array A has a value 2 which is greater than the upper bound of 1" error:

```
Program Main

    implicit none

    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: a
    allocate(a(1))

    print *, a(2)

End Program Main
```

then why doesn't this code also throw the error:

```
Program Main

    implicit none

    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: a
    allocate(a(0))

    print *, a(2)

End Program Main
```

It obviously gives undefined behavior, but it doesn't throw an error.

Edit: Full command line argument list as requested in comments

```
/nologo /debug:full /Od /Warn:interfaces /module:"Debug\\" /object:"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc160.db" /traceback /check:all /libs:dll /threads /dbglibs /c
```

Comment: Probably just a bug in the bounds checker in your compiler. Report to the vendor through the usual channels.

Comment: Interestingly ifx 2023.2.0 20230721 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 within WSL also fails to give an error for out of bounds when the second program is compiled with  `ifx -check all`.. However ifx does give an uninitialised variable error on exit after printing zero. Ifort behaves as above. BTW an improvement to the question would be to edit it to include the exact compilation line, assuming you are using command line. I'm assuming some version of Windows as well.

Comment: not using command line, but I can add the command options from visual studio.

Comment: There is really nothing we could answer, really. The compiler developers have to sort it out.

Comment: fair enough. To me the answer is that it isn't intended Fortran behavior and that it is a bug. If anyone wants to post that then I would accept it.

Comment: The Fortran standard doesn't require bound checking (and more generally it doesn't require any runtime check). So, strictly speaking the observed behavior is conformant to the Fortran standard, even if the code is not conformant: the behavior is undefined, which means that the execution may continue. Rather, this can be considered as a bug in ifort: as soon as the /check:all flag is set, this out of bound access should probably be reported.